# Can not call a class from another package. Package does not exist error

Tags: java, package

My classpath

> E:\classes\sample

I am running from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.4\bin

Source Code for E:\classes\sample\Test1\sample1.java

```
package sample.Test1;

class Sample1
{
    public void printThis()
    {
        System.out.println("WE are in sample1");
    }
}
```

Source Code for E:\classes\sample\db\sample2.java

```
package sample.Test2;
import sample.Test1.Sample1;

class Sample2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Main Class \n");
        Sample1 s = new Sample1();
        s.printThis();
    }
}
```

When I am compiling Sample2.java it is showing error. Sample1.java already compiled. Please help me..

Comment: You don't "call" a class, and a source file isn't the same as a class name· Please show your code, and how you're trying to compile it.

Comment: You need .class files, not .java: the first are the compiled ones, the second the source.

Comment: Yes I have the compiled class file for sample2.java. How I am running is c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.4\bin\javac E:\classes\sample\source\sample1.java

Comment: run `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.4\bin\javac E:\classes\sample\source\sample1`

Comment: Your folder names does not match your packages, Java compiler will create folders according to package names and put compiled classes there.

Comment: Yeah. I changed that and got the answer. If I want to use sample as a package my classpath should be E:\classes. Thank you all....

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't compile is your have default visibility on your first class (not `public`), so it can only be "seen" by classes in the same package. Your second class is in a different package, so it can't use it.

To fix, add the keyword `public` to your classes:

```
public class Sample1 {
```

#### Edit:

Still got a problem? I would just use an IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). It will tell you what the problem is and help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks. but still the same error..